# create a triangle wit yourself using signal strength between two points (2 access points)

Tags: java, android, triangulation

I am trying to create a triangulation method and I have the following:

1. Coordinates of 3 access points needed for the triangulation method
2. signal strength readings from each of the access points (dmb)

So the first thing I am trying to do is create a triangle using two of the access points. I will need to do an approximation of distance vs signal strength to figure out where I am between the two access points. Could somebody help me with this procedure.

Comment: So, you want to solve the 1-dimensional problem between two access points before you solve the 2-dimensional problem between all three? It's not really clear from your question.

Comment: is that not the way you figure out triangulation and once the step above is complete you use the third access point??

Comment: Had to make it a full answer because the explanation was too big for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make certain assumptions in an ideal network setting:

- All three routers are consistent.
- They're the same strength at the same distance.

With those, you can consider signal strength to be a direct replacement of distance.

Now, this distance is in a radius around each router and it doesn't give you angle information you'd need to use the classical triangulation method, however, you now have 3 circles around your routers telling you where each routers sees the device. If you find the one point at which all three circles intersect (there is at most one), that is the location of the device.

If you get a situation in which there's some deviation that there's no "exact" 3-circle intersection point, if you average the three closest 2-circle intersection points, you'll get roughly where they are.

Realistically, you'll get something like [image: this]

Comment: that makes more sense. Is there a method of checking the intersection point of the 3 circles?

Comment: Again, that is assuming a perfect world, so you might not get a that lovely "single point". Here's the math for it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Two circles intersect at as many as two points. Three circles intersect at at most one point. You're going to want to find all 6 two-circle intersections and use those to get a rough idea of where the perfect three-circle intersection would have been if it existed (tends to be the average, if I remember correctly).